# How to describe your career profile to a recruiter or interviewer?

Tags: interviewing

What would be the best way or is there a pattern of how to describe your career profile for the first time to a recruiter/interviewer on the phone or to a recruiter/interviewer face to face? without going on a tangent and looking/sounding stupid?

For example: Recruiter: So tell me a little about yourself? What have you been working on recently? etc.

Comment: It's too broad of a question. It's a complete training module. :)

Comment: Yes, it is a broad question but that is because the answer is also too broad. Any suggestion would be helpful than none!

Comment: Your CV tells a lot about the "what", try to focus on the why's and the how's so that your career path makes some sense...

Answer (score 2):

> So tell me a little about yourself?

Tell them about yourself.

> What have you been working on recently?

Tell them what you've been working on recently.

These aren't trick questions. There's no "magical" answer. Answer them honestly.

Comment: It all seems so simple...

Answer (score 0):

There is no pattern for you to describe yourself. As mention by joeqwerty, you just need to answer honestly. Just describe everything about yourself. But make sure it is a difference with your information inside your resume. Don't give an answer similar to what inside your resume. Go tell a different story. The interviewer just wants to know your background.

For what have you been working on recently? Just tell everything you have done. Again, honest. Maybe the interviewer will interest with what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I've always struggled with writing/talking about myself too. My advice would be, get a friend or relative to write something for you (bonus points if they're familiar with the work you do), take the parts you like, and roll with it.